# Will there be any performance issues using panda libraries within pyspark

Tags: pandas, pyspark

I am a newbie to python/panda/pyspark. Currently using panda packages for excel data manipulation, extraction and storage to database etc. I am told that as the data volume increases, panda may be a disadvantage and instead i should use pyspark. Also, I understand panda libraries are available within pyspark. Will there be any performance issues/limitations in future if I use panda functions within pyspark?

Have not tested performance or limitations, awaiting guidance from experts

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.